# Competing designs for nuclear pulse-propelled spaceships

Tags: nuclear-pulse-propulsion, nuclear-propulsion

I have been doing research on Project Orion. This was a canceled NASA program to build massive spaceships that were blasted into space by exploding nuclear charges. I have seen two schools of design in these concepts. Some of these Orions look like gigantic tank shells, but other designs look more cigar shaped...but still chonky. What are the advantages or disadvantages of either design?

Comment: This doesn't look like a worldbuilding problem, more like a space exploration one, for which there is a dedicated SE

Comment: Winchell Chung's [Atomic Rockets](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/) is the obligatory starting point.

Comment: This needs to be rephrased as a worldbuilding question or it needs to move elsewhere. What is the worldbuilding goal of your question? Do you need a ship that performs a specific function?

Comment: @DWKraus I am voting to move it elsewhere; while it does have some worldbuilding value, the folks at SpaceExploration (or possibly Engineering?) can provide better information. That being said, I don't think that the actual *question* needs to be modified; there is only one question, and it is relatively specific in what it asks for.

Comment: Please don't post the exact same question on two different stack exchange sites.

Answer (score -3):

Well, for manmade objekts in space (at least those you can enter and live in or use for transportation like stations, rockets and so on) a sphere ist the best solution as it holds best against the internal pressure. Its most stable and has the smallest loss of energy (mainly temperature). On the other hand it is much more easy and cost-efficient to build cylinders instead, as they are not much more then bend plates basicaly (and rockets are still build mainly from steel), therefore most rockets are cylindric with a bullet-like head. The last one is primary for efficiency around the start as for moving through the atmosphere the laws of aerodynamics still apply. The type of engine doesn't influence it that much to change it from usual rockets. Here ist your 'tank shell' the easier, more cost-efficient build, the 'cigarette' has bettee aerodynamics but costs more in production.

Comment: This isn't really a meaningful answer for this specific question about NPP ships.